# How to search fields with '-' characters in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search. I have got following document where one of the field "eventId" has "-" in value.
When i try to search with complete value of eventId, i don't get any results.

```
Sample Document app/event
 {
     "tags": {}
         "eventId": "cc98d57b-c6bc-424c-b54c-df1e3df0d942",
 }
```

I haven't created any explicit settings for my index.
Thanks.

Comment: Which query are you using?

Answer (score 1):

you should check if the tokenizer splits your value into multiple fields. Maybe your value is stored as 5 fields: "cc98d57b", "c6bc", "424c", "b54c" and "df1e3df0d942"

You can analyze that with the 'Kopf' Plugin (https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf).

If that is your problem you should change your field mapping, so that the value is not analyzed ("index" : "not_analyzed").

For an example how to set that mapping see here: [Elasticsearch mapping settings 'not_analyzed' and grouping by field in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620471/elasticsearch-mapping-settings-not-analyzed-and-grouping-by-field-in-java)

After that, you should be able to search for your specific value.