# Elasticsearch mapping settings 'not_analyzed' and grouping by field in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to group the results so that they are grouped by category.

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("search")
                .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("category").field("category").size(0))
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

The code above creates aggregations but I'm running into a problem where **strings with hyphens in them** are being separated and put into their own 'Bucket'.

From what I've read I need to change the mapping settings so that the category is not analysed but I'm not sure how to do this. Is this done when writing to Elasticsearch or when reading? How is it set exactly?

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov care to comment? I've been through the documentation and I have more specific question related to the Java API

Comment: You need to change your data mapping - read the docs. No matter if you use java api for that or not - mapping is changed once, do it in the way you prefer

Comment: Okay. I'm quite new to this, could you perhaps explain how I'd go about doing it in Java?

Comment: `client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To apply elasticsearch mapping using java api,

**STEP 1) First create your mapping for the Elasticsearch type in a json file,**

eg. `resources/Customer.json`

```
{
    "Customer" : {
                  "settings" : {
                  }, 
                  "properties"   : { 
                    "category" : { "type":"String" , "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                      } 
                   }
              }
      }
}
```

STEP 2) create a java method to apply mapping from a json file, (see complete example [here](https://github.com/prayagupd/gccount/blob/master/elasticsearch/src/groovy/eccount/EsEmbeddedNode.groovy#L174))

```
class EsUtils {

  public static Client client

  public static void applyMapping(String index, String type, String location) throws Exception {

            String source = readJsonDefn(location);

            if (source != null) {
                PutMappingRequestBuilder pmrb = client.admin().indices()
                                                      .preparePutMapping(index)
                                                      .setType(type);
                pmrb.setSource(source);
                MappingListener mappingListener = new MappingListener(pmrb)

                // Create type and mapping
                Thread thread = new Thread(mappingListener)

                thread.start();
                while (!mappingListener.processComplete.get()) {
                    System.out.println("not complete yet. Waiting for 100 ms")
                    Thread.sleep(100);

                }

            } else {
                   System.out.println("mapping error");
            }

       }

       public static String readJsonDefn(String url) throws Exception {
                 //implement it the way you like 
              StringBuffer bufferJSON = new StringBuffer();

              FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(url).absolutePath);
              DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(input);
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

              String line;

              while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                             bufferJSON.append(line);
              }
              br.close();
              return bufferJSON.toString();
       }
    }
```

**STEP 3) call applyMapping() method passing your es client,**

```
String index = "search"; //yourIndex
String type  = "Customer";
String location = "resources/Customer.json";

EsUtils.client = yourClient; //pass your client
EsUtils.applyMapping(index, type, location);
```

**STEP 4) query as you want**,

```
SearchRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareSearch("search");
builder.addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("categoryterms")
                                          .field("category").size(0))
SearchResponse response = builder.execute().actionGet();
```

### Complete Reference

[Elasticsearch apply mapping](https://github.com/prayagupd/gccount/blob/master/elasticsearch/src/groovy/eccount/EsEmbeddedNode.groovy#L174)